# How can I get ALL photo from the facebook album?

Tags: facebook

I know this topic is quite hot, but my problem is "half the problem" in the coding.

I have a facebook album that contain 266 photos. I use jquery and FQL to request the album id, then get all photo id and their src from the album. The code works good. But I notice that I can only get 102 photos nor 266 photos.

How can I get completely all photos in the facebook album?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found the answer after I had some little try in graph.facebook.com
The FQL allow us to use "limit" number. It looks like facebook default set the limit number to 100. That means, if we does not setup any limit number in the FQL, it will only get 100 record in the FQL.

I add the "limit 1000" in the FQL and get the photo again, it show up the 266 photos correctly.